# Microsoft Graph Explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to add Device.Read and Device.Command permissions to Graph Explorer.  When I open the permissions and add them I'm told I need admin approval, although these specific permissions do not require approval.  I want to add these permissions without taking away existing admin approvals.  How do I do this?

Comment: I think this is related to https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-explorer/issues/102. Can you open an issue in the repo for this?

Comment: Added issue 138: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-explorer/issues/138

Comment: This issue has been resolved.